# Is there any way how to create an IQueryable from HQL?

Tags: linq, hql, iqueryable, linq-to-nhibernate, queryover

We want to employ HQL(IQueryOver/ICriteria) in our data layer of application but we want to publish IQueryable for layers above the data layer based on our query in HQL. The reason is simple. It seems that HQL is a better way how to specify more complex queries (please feel free to be opposed to the opinion). There was a way how to achieve that in a previous version of NHibernate (we currently have 3.3.1.4000) using ICriteria. You can find [here](http://chadly.net/2009/10/creating-nhibernate-linq-query-from-arbitrary-criteria/) how to achieve that. Does anybody know how to do that with HQL in the new version?